# Python: Override static member in subclass

Tags: python, inheritance, static-members

I do have a an abstract base class `A`. This includes a static method `name`.
However, calling name() should yield the concrete subclass its name

The following example shows my problem

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    _name = "A"

    @staticmethod
    def name():
        return A._name # What to do here?

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    _name = "B"  # Or how to override A._name?
    def foo(self):
        return "Foo"

class C(A):
    _name = "C"
    def foo(self):
        return "Bar"

print(B().foo(), B.name()) # Should print: Foo, B
print(C().foo(), C.name()) # Shoudl print: Bar, C
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use a staticmethod here, you should use a classmethod. That takes the class as the first parameter, usually referred to as `cls`, so you can do `cls._name`.